# How to resort recursive array (array with children)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion

I'm trying to create a Drag and Drop component in which you can drag and drop each component to re-sort them.

For example, consider the following array

```
const myData = [
  { id: 0, text: "test one" },
  { id: 1, text: "test tow" },
  { id: 2, text: "test three" },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: "main",
    sub: [
      { id: 4, text: "sub 1" },
      { id: 5, text: "sub 2" },
    ],
  },
];
```

if the user drag the element (component) with the text `"test one"` and drop it under the element  `{ id: 4, text: "sub 1" },`
I want to reorder the data again to be like the following

```
const myData = [
  { id: 1, text: "test tow" },
  { id: 2, text: "test three" },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: "main",
    sub: [
      { id: 4, text: "sub 1" },
      { id: 0, text: "test one" },
      { id: 5, text: "sub 2" },
    ],
  },
];
```

this the component that renders the data.

```
import Draggable from "../Hooks/Draggable";

function TreeItems(state) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, myData);
    return state.map((item, index) => (
      <TreeItem
        key={index}
        nodeId={`${index}`}
        label={
          <div draggable={true} {...Draggable(item, index, Update)}>
            {item.text}
          </div>
        }
      >
        {item.sub && TreeItems(item.sub)}
      </TreeItem>
    ));
  }
```

I tried to delete the dragged element and then add it again in the child or parent array where the drop event occurs.

```
function deleting(state, action) {
  state.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.id === action.i.item.id) {
      state.splice(action.i.index, 1);
    } else if (item.sub) {
      deleting(item.sub, action);
    }
  });
  return state;
}
function adding(state, action) {
  state.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.id === action.item.id) {
      state.push(action.i.item);
      //max call stack size.
    } else if (item.sub) {
      adding(item.sub, action);
    }
  });
  return state;
}
function reordering(state, action) {
  // const { type, i, f, p } = action;
  const newState = deleting(state, action);
  const newState2 = adding(newState, action);
  return newState2;
}
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.REORDER:
      const newState = reordering(state, action);
      return [...newState];
    case ACTIONS.SUB:
      return state;
    case ACTIONS.UPSATETEXT:
      return state;
    default:
      console.log("none");
  }
}
```

but I got errors like

> max calls exeated

and I change the code in too many ways the deleting function work very fine but the adding function cause errors like max calls or I remember I change it in some way and it duplicate the drag-drop element instead of deleting add and then add it.

[CodeSandBox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-lake-d8rww?file=/src/Components/Tree.jsx)

- note the sandBox says can't import `material-ui` dependencies and I have no idea why but it works very fine on my local machine.

Comment: This line looks suspect to me: `state.splice(action.i.index, 1)`  Presumably the first argument to `splice` should be the iteration index, and have nothing to do with `action`.  That is `state.forEach((item, index) => /* ... */ state.splice(index, 1)` .

Comment: I'm passing the index throw the useReduc action it is just action = `{type:'blabla",i:{index:0,item:{blab bla}....}`

Comment: But note that splice call.  Your code says, "For each item in the state, if that item matches on id, then delete from the state the item at some fixed index."  Presumably you want to say, "For each item in the state, if that item matches on id, then delete from the state *that item*."  You can use the `index` parameter in the callback to `forEach` to do this.  But perhaps I'm just missing something fundamental.

Comment: Because this is asked in the context of React, you may be interested in the [Immutable](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/) library, or something like [Immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) library.

Comment: Scott, I'll circle back and answer this later today if I don't see an answer from you soon :D

Comment: @Thankyou: I won't have time before this evening, if then, so feel free.

Comment: @ScottSauyet you are right I can delete base on the index but it doesn't matter, also I the index may shift after the drag so I should just avoid it for now because i have a bigger problem to solve

Comment: @ScottSauyet The component work now on [CodeSandbox] (https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-lake-d8rww?file=/src/App.js) and its create the same errors and bugs.

Comment: The code on CodeSandbox still has the same issue I describe.  I have no idea what else might be wrong, but that error is basic.  Things can't possibly run properly until it's fixed.

Comment: @ScottSauyet action is just name I give it to a JOSN that already have the index of the draged element, and action.f = index of the draover element.

Comment: I'm afraid I make no sense of this.  But I also don't have access to your codesandbox (blocked by company policy) code, so maybe that would make it clear.  Nonetheless, this is *very* strange code.